# Canvas.drawImage() FAIL on iOS mobile safari/chrome with 3000px JPGs

Tags: ios, html5-canvas, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I'm trying to resize an image on the client side using "file[type=input]" and an html5 canvas. The code works fine in desktop chrome and android chrome -- and also in iOS when tested with a 2048px JPG.

But when I test with a photo from an iPhone 4S, `{"origW":3264,"origH":2448}`, I get a bad result in iOS safari/chrome (see screenshot) . It must be a memory problem, but is there a workaround?

Use the jsfiddle to try it yourself http://jsfiddle.net/CBuJF/32/

```
function downsizeImgDataURL (origImg, targetImg){
    consolelog("resizing dataURL to 320px");
    var ctx, filesize, img, canvas, resizeH, resizeW, resizedDataURL, targetWidth;

    targetWidth = 320;
    if (origImg.width > targetWidth) {
        resizeH = origImg.height / origImg.width * targetWidth;
        resizeW = targetWidth;
    }
    filesize = [origImg.src.length];
    consolelog("*** downsize canvas, IMG.onload(): downsized=" + JSON.stringify([resizeW, resizeH]));

    canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = resizeW
    canvas.height = resizeH
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(origImg, 0, 0, resizeW, resizeH);
    resizedDataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    filesize.push(resizedDataURL.length);
    consolelog("*** downsize result, filesize=" + JSON.stringify(filesize));

    targetImg.src = resizedDataURL;
}
```

[image: canvas.drawImage() FAIL on iOS with hi-res JPG]

Comment: I also checked on an iPad, got the same result in both mobile Safari & Chrome. It seems to be either an iOS 7 memory problem, but I have no clue how to track it down. suggestions?

Comment: Here is another test site that uses canvas/context2d to resize: http://www.3site.eu/jstests/resample/  BTW, I could have sworn that I got it to work on iOS -- but after I tore the code apart and tried it in my codebase, neither version worked with a 3000px iphone photo.